# How to detect the OS / Peripherals with Kivy?

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy

I'm writing a program with Kivy.

Under "desktop" OSes it would be normal to use the keyboard for input, and my code does so.

```
class ProgLayout( FloatLayout ):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super( ProgLayout, self ).__init__(**kwargs)
        # Keyboard Handling (if any)
        self.keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self.keyboard_closed, self)
        self.keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self.on_keyboard_down)
        self.keyboard.bind(on_key_up=self.on_keyboard_up)
        self.key_states = { 'up':False, 'down':False, 'left':False, 'right':False }

    def on_keyboard_down( self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers ):
        #print("ON_KEYBOARD_DOWN")
        #print('The key', keycode, 'have been pressed')
        #print(' - text is %r' % text)
        #print(' - modifiers are %r' % modifiers)

        junk, key = keycode
        keymap = { 'up':Directions.NORTH, 'down':Directions.SOUTH, 'left':Directions.WEST, 'right':Directions.EAST }
        if ( key in ( 'up', 'down', 'left', 'right' ) ):
            self.key_states[ key ] = True
            self.handleKeys()

    def on_keyboard_up( self, keyboard, keycode ):
        #print("ON_KEYBOARD_UP")
        junk, key = keycode
        if ( key in ( 'up', 'down', 'left', 'right' ) ):
            self.key_states[ key ] = False
            self.handleKeys()
```

However, when the app starts under Android (I suspect) opening the keyboard induces the onscreen-keyboard to appear.  Obviously the soft-keyboard can be dismissed, but a better solution is to only open the keyboard if a hardware keyboard is present - or just not automatically use it for Android.

Is there a way to determine if a physical keyboard is present on Kivy?

Is there a way to determine if my app is running on Android (ah, I guess `platform.system()` or `sys.platform`).

EDIT: buildozer fails to build the .APK if I include `sys` or `platform` in the `buildozer.spec` manifest.  Importing `sys` still seems to work despite this.  But on my android tablet, `sys.platform` reports "linux", so that's not a way forward.

Comment: Try using `from kivy.utils import platform`

Comment: There should be a way to prevent the on-screen keyboard opening automatically, but I don't know if there actually is. If not, that's a bug in Kivy.

Answer (score 7):

As the commenter @Erik points out, the solution to determining the current platform is `kivy.utils.platform`.

```
from kivy.utils import platform

...

if ( kivy.utils.platform != 'android' ):
    # open the keyboard, since we're not android
```

As the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.utils.html#kivy.utils.platform) states:

> A string identifying the current operating system. It is one of: ‘win’, ‘linux’, ‘android’, ‘macosx’, ‘ios’ or ‘unknown’.

Answer (score 2):

For what concerns the platform, it's sufficient to:

```
import kivy

print(kivy.platform)
```

For what concerns the virtual keyboard, there is the [`VKeyboard`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.vkeyboard.html?highlight=keyboard) module in Kivy, but I can't really read any of the attributes this class should have... strange enough.